# Авторизация с if

Tags: java, if, условия

Не заходит в условие, что не так?

```
private static JTextField log_in_tf;
    private static JTextField pass_in_tf;
    private static JButton bt_login;
    static String get_login;
    static String get_pass;     
        get_login = log_in_tf.getText();
        get_pass = pass_in.getText();
        bt_login.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(get_login.equals("admin") && get_pass.equals("A7845")){
                    System.out.println("В условии.");
                    Signed.main(null);
                    frame.setVisible(false);
                }

                else {
                    JFrame frameErr = new JFrame("Ошибка");
                    frameErr.setBounds(550, 245, 200, 100);
                    frameErr.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE); 
                    frameErr.setResizable(false);
                    frameErr.addWindowStateListener(new WindowStateListener(){
                        @Override
                        public void windowStateChanged(WindowEvent e){
                            frameErr.setState(JFrame.NORMAL);
                        }
                    });
                    frameErr.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
                    frameErr.setVisible(true);
                }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Проверьте чему равны `get_login` и `get_pass`. Если они совпадают со строками, то можно прописать их в коде и сократить код в вопросе до трех строчек.

Comment: Спасибо, я проверил - get_pass не туда обращалось и, соответственно, сравнивалось не то значение, которое нужно.

Answer (score 0):

Вызовы `getText()` должны быть внутри обработчика события.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
  String  get_login = log_in_tf.getText();
  String  get_pass = pass_in.getText();
  System.out.println("[" + get_login + "] and [" + get_pass + "]");
  if(get_login.equals("admin") && get_pass.equals("A7845")){
    ...
```

Comment: Прокомментирую: автор впороса получает данные из формы до нажатия кнопки, очевидно, в тот момент, когда в форму ничего не введено.

Comment: все равно не заходит (скрин добавил)

Comment: Да, проверка помогла, get_pass обращалось не туда